# Setting a custom NSObject to an uneditable state

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

I have a custom NSObject that is being altered by a multitude of sources and I want to at times stop these variables from being altered.  What is the easiest method of doing this without using an "if" statement at every one of the hundreds of times I edit this object.

Any help and direction will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: what is wrong with the "if"? Do you think that that "if" is so performance critical that you want to "optimize it away"?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the if statement, I just am hoping there is a method for doing this that doesn't result in me spending a day and a half adding if statements XD

Comment: Do u want to prevent access or changes to that object?

Comment: I asked whether u wanted to prevent WRITES or even READS, which one is it??

Comment: O, my apologies I miss read that.  Writes is what id like to stop. I will still need to view the object and reference it./